# Eliminar numeros de un DataFrame que superen el numero 30

Tags: python, jupyter

Tengo un dataframe con 60.000 datos y necesito sacar promedios mensuales pero necesito eliminar los numeros que sean mayores a 30 he intentado varios condicionales pero no me funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De qué columna estamos hablando? ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Bienvenido Juan Martinez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, cualquier código como texto no como imagen. También agrega un ejemplo de los datos y que es lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

Existen muchas maneras de hacerlo, como puedes verificarlo aquí:

[Filtrar datos en un dataframe por valores](http://pyciencia.blogspot.com/2015/05/obtener-y-filtrar-datos-de-un-dataframe.html)

El que prefiero es por la definición de criterios. La forma general sería:

```
df_filtrado = df_original[criterio]
```

En tu caso, si tu dataframe se llama Suba:

```
menores_que_30 =Suba["columna"]<30
```

Identificas la columna y la relación a aplicar. Y luego lo aplicas al dataframe:

```
Suba_menores_que_30 = Suba[menores_que_30].copy()
```

Nota que usar el método copy() preservará tu dataframe original (Suba) cuando modifiques el que estás trabajando (Suba_menores_que_30 )

Comment: La respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).